# Importing .xliff localization files in Xcode 6.0

Tags: ios, import, xcode6, xliff

Apple has recently introduced a new process for translating files. You no longer have to use genstrings/ibtool for generating `.strings` file - instead you simply use the `.xliff` files export/import tool built right into Xcode:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

Unfortunately when I'm trying to import right from Xcode, it crashes.
I wanted to test it out using `xcodebuild -importLocalizations` as is described here (page 68):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.pdf

It turns out that there's no such `importLocalizations` argument for xcodebuild (although there is an `exportLocalization`)?! (`man` command confirms this) Am I missing something? This has also been tested in Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Apple talk about xcodebuild -importLocalizations in their pdf and video but it seems it's not supported yet in Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: Mine crashes too.  I made a sample project and can successfully round trip a pseudo localization, but it doesn't work with my real app.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: There is no description of the importLocalizations command on that page in that pdf. (Anymore?)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I get in the same situation now.

Answer (score 4):

It importing via the command line works now on Xcode 7

```
xcodebuild -importLocalizations \
           -project MyProj.xcodeproj \
           -localizationPath es.xlf
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the crash is, if the xliff file contains any empty localisable strings, then Xcode will crash while importing it.

Re-create the xliff will and make sure there are no strings left blank.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and **in my case** I figured out that the running SourceTree application was the problem! I closed it and reimported successfully.
Maybe it modifies something while importing.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.3.1 has fixed bug with crashing while importing localisations from xliffs. To prevent Xcode before 7.3.1 from crashing, you have to include **all localised strings** from **all targets** in your xliff file

Answer (score -2):

The `.xliff` localization files can now be imported/exported from Xcode's UI:

Select your **project file** in the Xcode UI. Then use the `Editor` menu.

Export:
`Xcode > Menu Bar > Editor > Export For Localization...`

Import:
`Xcode > Menu Bar > Editor > Import Localizations...`

[image: Xcode Menu > Editor > Import/Export]